# How do I change the background colour of a cell programically? (not onchange, not depending on value, not on creation)

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have researched the issue on the internet, but I'm unable to find the answer.

I would like to change background colour of a specific handsontable cell. Please note, I don't mean setting the colour on creation of the handsontable object, I also don't mean setting colour after changing values in the table.

Ideally I'd be able to do something like that: (pseudocode below)

```
function setColour(row,col,colour){
  hot.cells(row,col).backgroundColour=colour
 }

function makeItRed(){
  setColour(0,4,"#FF0000") //this sets the cell in the 1st row and 5th column to red
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

EDIT:

For the purporse of the question, please assume `makeItRed()` function call will be assigned to a button.

EDIT2: 
Stackoverflow doesn't allow putting names of techologies in the question title, it's about HANDSONTABLE not HTML table.

Comment: Perhaps because the question doesn't make sense. One question you will answer is **when?**

Comment: @Adam Azad. When I call the makeItRed() function. What is unclear in my question?

Comment: But that requires an event to call it, like a button click or as a response to change in the environment.

Comment: please assume it'll be assigned to a button although I had no idea the answer would be different whether it's assigned to a button, called manually from console, or on a timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `:nth-child()` selectors:

https://repl.it/@ryanpcmcquen/PricklyJumboBlackbear

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const setColour = (row, col, colour) => {
        const cell = document.querySelector(`table tr:nth-child(${row + 1}) td:nth-child(${col + 1})`);
        cell.style.backgroundColor = colour;
    };
    
    const makeItRed = () => {
        setColour(0, 2, "#FF0000");
    };
    
    document.querySelector('.color-me').addEventListener('click', () => {
        makeItRed();
    });
});
```

```css
table, table tr, table td {
    border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td>0, 0</td>
              <td>0, 1</td>
              <td>0, 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>1, 0</td>
              <td>1, 1</td>
              <td>1, 2</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
      <button class="color-me">Color me</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You'll have to increment the `row` and `col` variables by 1, since `:nth-child()` is not zero based.

Comment: question is about handsontable

Comment: @LucasSeveryn, this will still work. `Handsontable` still builds an HTML table. The same rules apply.

Answer (score 0):

Handsontable allows you to set a [custom renderer](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.38.0/demo-custom-renderers.html) that would be colouring your background:

```
const bgRenderer = function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    td.style.backgroundColor = '#cbd9e4';
};

function makeItRed() {
    hot.getCellMeta(0,0).renderer = bgRenderer;
    hot.render();
};
```

If you use other renderers (like `Handsontable.renderers.DateRenderer`), you would need to cover them too.

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/be5wy478/9/).

BTW, @ryanpcmcquen's way to colour will work, but the background wouldn't stick - see the same jfiddle.

Comment: does this mean I have to create a custom renderer for every colour i might want to use?